Unable to read text file in Glue job
I am trying to read the schema from a text file under the same package as the code but cannot read that file using the AWS glue job. I will use that schema for creating a dataframe using Pyspark. I can load that file locally. I am zipping the code files as .zip, placing them under the s3 bucket, and then referencing them in the glue job. Every other thing works fine. No problem there. But when I try the below code it doesn't work.
file_path = os.path.join(Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.relpath(__file__))), "verifications.txt")
multiline_data = None
with open(file_path, 'r') as data_file:
   multiline_data = data_file.read()
self.logger.info(f"Schema is {multiline_data}")
           

This code throws the below error:
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'src.zip/src/ingestion/jobs/verifications.txt'  

I also tried with abs_path but it didn't help either. The same block of code works fine locally.
I also tried directly passing the "./verifications.txt" path but no luck.
So how do I read this file?

As @Bogdan mentioned the way to do this is use S3 to store the verifications.txt file. Here's some example code using boto3
import boto3

# Hardcoded S3 bucket/key (these are normally passed in as Glue Job params)
s3_bucket = 'your-bucket-name'
s3_key = 'path/to/verifications.txt'

# Read data from S3 using boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
multiline_data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

If you want to access the file from inside the zip directly (given your comment) you might have to get more fancy...
import boto3
import zipfile
import io

# Initialize boto3 client for S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Define the bucket name and the zip file key
bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
zip_file_key = 'path/to/src.zip'

# Download the zip file from S3
zip_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=zip_file_key)
buffer = io.BytesIO(zip_obj['Body'].read())

# Open the zip file in memory
with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, 'r') as zip_ref:
    # List all files in the zip
    print("Files in the zip:", zip_ref.namelist())

    # Open and read a specific file within the zip without extracting
    with zip_ref.open('verifications.txt') as file:
        text_content = file.read().decode('utf-8')
        print("Contents of the text file:", text_content)


My question remains the same. So as per you guys, we can't use file operations on the zip file? Any links supporting your justifications pls?

I think there's two dimensions here, the first and most important is that S3 is an 'object store' and doesn't support normal Python file operations like reading files directly, the second is how do I read something from a zip file without unzipping it. Hopefully my updated answer covers both dimensions. :)

Yeah makes sense

AWS Glue scripts typically run in a managed environment, meaning your file is not visible to the ETL script. The reason the import works on your local machine is that the file is accessible from there since both are on the same machine. For such jobs, consider using S3 to store your files.

So you mean file operations won't work in Glue? @Bogdan
